# Inheritance between two projects in one solution

Tags: c#

I have two project within one solution. In one project there's an abstract class A with abstract methods.This class I want to be inherited by class B from the second project. How to do so?
First project:

```
   namespace WpfApp1
{ 
    public abstract class A 
     {
        protected string text1;
        public abstract void Method1();
     }
}
```

Second project:

```
    namespace WpfApp2
{ 
    public class B 
     {

     }
}
```

Comment: Reference the 1st project in the 2nd one?

Comment: Well, why don't use just interfaces and dependency injection?

Comment: @andrey.shedko Wait what why?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a project reference from the project containing class B to the project containing class A.
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx for a detailed description.

Answer (score 0):

The basic way to go for is to add reference of second project into the first one and use it . That is the basic level to go for . You basically cant use it without referencing .